# Backbone - URL Encoded with diacritics in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have a search form that redirects the user to `search/thetermusersearched` where `thetermusersearched` is the exact value he entered. All this with the navigate function provided by Backbone.

This is all fine when I use strings in English (masa de calcat), but when I add diacritics in the input (masă de călcat) I get the **route function fired twice.**

The problem I have is in Firefox and Safari (the later in Mac and iOS)

I tried using `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent` when I use the `navigate`, but no success.

---

HTML

```
<div id="view-goes-here">
  <a href="#" data-string="masa de calcat">One alert</a>
  <a href="#" data-string="masă de călcat">Two alerts</a>
</div>
```

---

JS

```
var R = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        'results/:query': 'results'
    },
    results: function(query) {
        alert('Route triggered: ' + decodeURIComponent(query));
    }
});
var myR = new R;
Backbone.history.start();

$(function(){
  $('a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var href = $(this).data('string');
   href = 'results/' + encodeURIComponent(href);
   console.log(href);
   myR.navigate(href, {trigger: true});
  })
})
```

---

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/qcged76e/4/

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

I get a double alert with both links in your fiddle. 
I tried using escape after encode which seems to work:

```
href =  'results/' + escape(encodeURIComponent(href));
```